# Why when working with CNAME does the SSL certificate not work?

Tags: ssl, cname

We use a third party shopping cart platform, we are not looking to change as of now.
When using the platforms catalog store option, the SSL certificate does not work.
As a result the site shows as unsafe. How can we fix this?

Comment: You need to provide a little bit more details. What url shows unsafe, what urls do you have specified in the certificate?

Comment: To cite from the referenced question: *"Whether your DNS entry uses a CNAME or an A record doesn't matter. __What matters is the host name the client is trying to connect to__. It must match one of the Subject Alternative Names in the certificate of the server providing that resource (or, failing that, it must match the CN RDN of the cert's Subject DN)."*